# BillingClient is not connecting to Play Services using v6.0.1

Tags: android, in-app-billing, android-billing, play-billing-library, billingclient

I am implementing in app services using in app billing library v6.0.1. Strangely the Billing Client is not connecting to Play Services.

I have tested the following code in both release and debug versions but to no avail.

> **The connection to play services code is as under:**

```
billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(MainActivity.this)
            .setListener(purchasesUpdatedListener)
            .enablePendingPurchases()
            .build();


    boolean check = billingClient.isReady();

    //start the connection after initializing the billing client
    if(check)
        establishConnection();
    else
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Billing client is not ready",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

> **The establish connection method is as under:**

```
    private void establishConnection() {
        billingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener() {
    
            @Override
            public void onBillingSetupFinished( BillingResult billingResult) {
    
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,billingResult.getResponseCode(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    
                if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                    // The BillingClient is ready. You can query purchases here.
                    //showProducts();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Billing client is successfully connected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Billing client failed to connect",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            @Override
            public void onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
                // Try to restart the connection on the next request to
                // Google Play by calling the startConnection() method.
                //establishConnection();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Billing connection is disconnected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
}
```

The line is always returning false due to unknown reason.

```
boolean check = billingClient.isReady();
```

Please help me to find a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should call establishConnection method when billingClient.isReady() = false. It means the connection does not establish yet.